# Composite keys fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Can one do this on a fluent nhibernate ?

When I try to save, I am profiding the profile and the scenario objects and the id's are not null.

Nhibernate complains that it can't insurt NULL for ProfileID column. Fluent Nhibernate doesn't know how to get to the Profile.ID ?

```
CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Profile.ID, "ProfileID").KeyProperty(x => x.Scenario.ID, "ScenarioID");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use this instead:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(x => x.Profile, "ProfileID")
    .KeyReference(x => x.Scenario, "ScenarioID");
```

Comment: yep, thanks Cole, yes I discovered this eventually. I had to use KeyReference for the mapping to work.